# OpenOffice API: Saving Impress (presentation) document as self-contained file

Tags: java, openoffice.org, openoffice-impress

When I save a with the 'MS PowerPoint 97' filter, image files used in `GraphicObjectShape` objects are just linked, not contained in the file.

Is there a property of this filter or a document-property to make OOo create a self-contained file (image files embedded instead of linked)?

**Edit:**

The [XLinkageSupport](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/embed/XLinkageSupport.html) object has a `breakLink` function. Any clues how to obtain these interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed images into an OOo document thru the `com.sun.star.drawing.BitmapTable` object. The following function will take the document (its `XMultiServiceFactory` interface), a `File` object pointing to the image file of your choice and an internalName which has to be unique, embeds the image and returns the URL pointing to the embedded instance.

```
/**
 * Embeds an image into the document and gets back the new URL.
 *
 * @param factory Factory interface of the document.
 * @param file Image file.
 * @param internalName Name of the image used inside the document.
 * @return URL of the embedded image.
 */
public static String embedLocalImage(XMultiServiceFactory factory, File localFile, String internalName) {

    // future return value
    String newURL = null;

    // URL of the file (note that BitmapTable expects URLs starting with
    // "file://" rather than just "file:". Also note that getRawPath() will
    // return an encoded URL (with special character in the form of %xx).
    String imageURL = "file://" + localFile.toURI().getRawPath();

    try {

        // get a BitmapTable object from the document (and get interface)
        Object bitmapTable = factory.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.BitmapTable");
        XNameContainer bitmapContainer = (XNameContainer)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XNameContainer.class, bitmapTable);

        // insert image by URL into the table
        bitmapContainer.insertByName(internalName, imageURL);

        // get interface
        XNameAccess bitmapAccess = (XNameAccess)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XNameAccess.class, bitmapTable);

        // get the embedded URL back
        newURL = (String)bitmapAccess.getByName(internalName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    // return the new (embedded) url
    return newURL;
}
```